# How can I append <td> dynamically according to the number of values in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I am creating a program where I get value from json and I want to show that value in a table. I am getting all the values in console but only the last arrays value is displayed in the table. So I want to append the  dynamically so that it will create new td according to the values in json file.

HTML Code:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Count:</td>
        <td id="count"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Created:</td>
        <td id="created"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lang:</td>
        <td id="lang"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ID:</td>
        <td id="id"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td id="Name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rate:</td>
        <td id="Rate"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>
        <td id="Date"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Time:</td>
        <td id="Time"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ask:</td>
        <td id="Ask"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bid:</td>
        <td id="Bid"></td>
    </tr>
```

In this file I have only one value for count, created and lang. Whereas I have 29 values for the rest of the fields.

Javascript file:

```
$.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDARS%22,%20%22USDAUD%22,%20%22USDBHD%22,%20%22USDBRL%22,%20%22USDGBP%22,%20%22USDCNY%22,%20%22USDHRK%22,%20%22USDDKK%22,%20%22USDEGP%22,%20%22USDSVC%22,%20%22USDEEK%22,%20%22USDETB%22,%20%22USDEUR%22,%20%22USDHKD%22,%20%22USDHUF%22,%20%22USDINR%22,%20%22USDIDR%22,%20%22USDJPY%22,%20%22USDKWD%22,%20%22USDNZD%22,%20%22USDNOK%22,%20%22USDPKR%22,%20%22USDPHP%22,%20%22USDPLN%22,%20%22USDRUB%22,%20%22USDSGD%22,%20%22USDZAR%22,%20%22USDSEK%22,%20%22USDCHF%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys', function (json) {

    // Set the variables from the query array
    //alert(json.query.results.rate.length);
    var count = json.query.count;
    console.log('Count : ', count);
    var created = json.query.created;
    console.log('Created : ', created);
    var lang = json.query.lang;
    console.log('Lang : ', lang);

    for(i=0; i<json.query.results.rate.length; i++)
    {
        var id = json.query.results.rate[i].id;
        console.log('ID : ', id);
        var name = json.query.results.rate[i].Name;
        console.log('Name : ', name);
        var rate = json.query.results.rate[i].Rate;
        console.log('Rate : ', rate);
        var date = json.query.results.rate[i].Date;
        console.log('Date : ', date);
        var time = json.query.results.rate[i].Time;
        console.log('Time : ', time);
        var ask = json.query.results.rate[i].Ask;
        console.log('Ask : ', ask);
        var bid = json.query.results.rate[i].Bid;
        console.log('Bid : ', bid);
//}
    // Set the table td text
    $('#count').text(count);
    $('#created').text(created);
    $('#lang').text(lang);
    $('#id').text(id);
    $('#Name').text(name);
    $('#Rate').text(rate);
    $('#Date').text(date);
    $('#Time').text(time);
    $('#Ask').text(ask);
    $('#Bid').text(bid);
    }
});
```

JSON data [(source)](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDARS%22,%20%22USDAUD%22,%20%22USDBHD%22,%20%22USDBRL%22,%20%22USDGBP%22,%20%22USDCNY%22,%20%22USDHRK%22,%20%22USDDKK%22,%20%22USDEGP%22,%20%22USDSVC%22,%20%22USDEEK%22,%20%22USDETB%22,%20%22USDEUR%22,%20%22USDHKD%22,%20%22USDHUF%22,%20%22USDINR%22,%20%22USDIDR%22,%20%22USDJPY%22,%20%22USDKWD%22,%20%22USDNZD%22,%20%22USDNOK%22,%20%22USDPKR%22,%20%22USDPHP%22,%20%22USDPLN%22,%20%22USDRUB%22,%20%22USDSGD%22,%20%22USDZAR%22,%20%22USDSEK%22,%20%22USDCHF%22%29&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys):

```
{"query":{"count":29,"created":"2015-07-07T07:33:27Z","lang":"nl-NL","results":{"rate":[{"id":"USDARS","Name":"USD/ARS","Rate":"9.1173","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"9.1214","Bid":"9.1173"},{"id":"USDAUD","Name":"USD/AUD","Rate":"1.3374","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"1.3376","Bid":"1.3374"},{"id":"USDBHD","Name":"USD/BHD","Rate":"0.3770","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.3790","Bid":"0.3770"},{"id":"USDBRL","Name":"USD/BRL","Rate":"3.1391","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"3.1392","Bid":"3.1391"},{"id":"USDGBP","Name":"USD/GBP","Rate":"0.6428","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.6428","Bid":"0.6428"},{"id":"USDCNY","Name":"USD/CNY","Rate":"6.2098","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"6.2104","Bid":"6.2098"},{"id":"USDHRK","Name":"USD/HRK","Rate":"6.8687","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"6.8988","Bid":"6.8687"},{"id":"USDDKK","Name":"USD/DKK","Rate":"6.7676","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"6.7701","Bid":"6.7676"},{"id":"USDEGP","Name":"USD/EGP","Rate":"7.7327","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"7.7352","Bid":"7.7327"},{"id":"USDSVC","Name":"USD/SVC","Rate":"8.7395","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"8.7445","Bid":"8.7395"},{"id":"USDEEK","Name":"N/A","Rate":"N/A","Date":"N/A","Time":"N/A","Ask":"N/A","Bid":"N/A"},{"id":"USDETB","Name":"USD/ETB","Rate":"20.6850","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"20.7880","Bid":"20.6850"},{"id":"USDEUR","Name":"USD/EUR","Rate":"0.9070","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.9070","Bid":"0.9070"},{"id":"USDHKD","Name":"USD/HKD","Rate":"7.7551","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"7.7552","Bid":"7.7551"},{"id":"USDHUF","Name":"USD/HUF","Rate":"286.5400","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"286.8600","Bid":"286.5400"},{"id":"USDINR","Name":"USD/INR","Rate":"63.3839","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"63.3990","Bid":"63.3839"},{"id":"USDIDR","Name":"USD/IDR","Rate":"13298.0000","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"13310.0000","Bid":"13298.0000"},{"id":"USDJPY","Name":"USD/JPY","Rate":"122.6850","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"122.7000","Bid":"122.6850"},{"id":"USDKWD","Name":"USD/KWD","Rate":"0.3027","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.3032","Bid":"0.3027"},{"id":"USDNZD","Name":"USD/NZD","Rate":"1.5032","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"1.5035","Bid":"1.5032"},{"id":"USDNOK","Name":"USD/NOK","Rate":"8.1378","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"8.1403","Bid":"8.1378"},{"id":"USDPKR","Name":"USD/PKR","Rate":"101.7300","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"101.7600","Bid":"101.7300"},{"id":"USDPHP","Name":"USD/PHP","Rate":"45.1575","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"45.1680","Bid":"45.1575"},{"id":"USDPLN","Name":"USD/PLN","Rate":"3.8149","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"3.8180","Bid":"3.8149"},{"id":"USDRUB","Name":"USD/RUB","Rate":"57.3045","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"57.3100","Bid":"57.3045"},{"id":"USDSGD","Name":"USD/SGD","Rate":"1.3539","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"1.3540","Bid":"1.3539"},{"id":"USDZAR","Name":"USD/ZAR","Rate":"12.4487","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"12.4562","Bid":"12.4487"},{"id":"USDSEK","Name":"USD/SEK","Rate":"8.4844","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"8.4852","Bid":"8.4844"},{"id":"USDCHF","Name":"USD/CHF","Rate":"0.9436","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.9437","Bid":"0.9436"}]}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off creating new rows instead of TD's:

```js
var json = {"query":{"count":29,"created":"2015-07-07T07:33:27Z","lang":"nl-NL","results":{"rate":[{"id":"USDARS","Name":"USD/ARS","Rate":"9.1173","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"9.1214","Bid":"9.1173"},{"id":"USDAUD","Name":"USD/AUD","Rate":"1.3374","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"1.3376","Bid":"1.3374"},{"id":"USDBHD","Name":"USD/BHD","Rate":"0.3770","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.3790","Bid":"0.3770"},{"id":"USDBRL","Name":"USD/BRL","Rate":"3.1391","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"3.1392","Bid":"3.1391"},{"id":"USDGBP","Name":"USD/GBP","Rate":"0.6428","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.6428","Bid":"0.6428"},{"id":"USDCNY","Name":"USD/CNY","Rate":"6.2098","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"6.2104","Bid":"6.2098"},{"id":"USDHRK","Name":"USD/HRK","Rate":"6.8687","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"6.8988","Bid":"6.8687"},{"id":"USDDKK","Name":"USD/DKK","Rate":"6.7676","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"6.7701","Bid":"6.7676"},{"id":"USDEGP","Name":"USD/EGP","Rate":"7.7327","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"7.7352","Bid":"7.7327"},{"id":"USDSVC","Name":"USD/SVC","Rate":"8.7395","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"8.7445","Bid":"8.7395"},{"id":"USDEEK","Name":"N/A","Rate":"N/A","Date":"N/A","Time":"N/A","Ask":"N/A","Bid":"N/A"},{"id":"USDETB","Name":"USD/ETB","Rate":"20.6850","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"20.7880","Bid":"20.6850"},{"id":"USDEUR","Name":"USD/EUR","Rate":"0.9070","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.9070","Bid":"0.9070"},{"id":"USDHKD","Name":"USD/HKD","Rate":"7.7551","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"7.7552","Bid":"7.7551"},{"id":"USDHUF","Name":"USD/HUF","Rate":"286.5400","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"286.8600","Bid":"286.5400"},{"id":"USDINR","Name":"USD/INR","Rate":"63.3839","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"63.3990","Bid":"63.3839"},{"id":"USDIDR","Name":"USD/IDR","Rate":"13298.0000","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"13310.0000","Bid":"13298.0000"},{"id":"USDJPY","Name":"USD/JPY","Rate":"122.6850","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"122.7000","Bid":"122.6850"},{"id":"USDKWD","Name":"USD/KWD","Rate":"0.3027","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.3032","Bid":"0.3027"},{"id":"USDNZD","Name":"USD/NZD","Rate":"1.5032","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"1.5035","Bid":"1.5032"},{"id":"USDNOK","Name":"USD/NOK","Rate":"8.1378","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"8.1403","Bid":"8.1378"},{"id":"USDPKR","Name":"USD/PKR","Rate":"101.7300","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"101.7600","Bid":"101.7300"},{"id":"USDPHP","Name":"USD/PHP","Rate":"45.1575","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"45.1680","Bid":"45.1575"},{"id":"USDPLN","Name":"USD/PLN","Rate":"3.8149","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"3.8180","Bid":"3.8149"},{"id":"USDRUB","Name":"USD/RUB","Rate":"57.3045","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"57.3100","Bid":"57.3045"},{"id":"USDSGD","Name":"USD/SGD","Rate":"1.3539","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"1.3540","Bid":"1.3539"},{"id":"USDZAR","Name":"USD/ZAR","Rate":"12.4487","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"12.4562","Bid":"12.4487"},{"id":"USDSEK","Name":"USD/SEK","Rate":"8.4844","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"8.4852","Bid":"8.4844"},{"id":"USDCHF","Name":"USD/CHF","Rate":"0.9436","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:33am","Ask":"0.9437","Bid":"0.9436"}]}}};

var count = json.query.count,
    created = json.query.created,
    lang = json.query.lang;

for(i=0; i<json.query.results.rate.length; i++) {
  var row = json.query.results.rate[i]; // Save a reference to the row.

  $("<tr>").appendTo($("#result"))      // Create new row, append it to the table's html.
    .append('<td>' + count + '</td>')   // Add all the data to the table.
    .append('<td>' + created + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + lang + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + row.id + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + row.Name + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + row.Rate + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + row.Date + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + row.Time + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + row.Ask + '</td>')
    .append('<td>' + row.Bid + '</td>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="result">
    <tr>
        <th>Count:</th>
        <th>Created:</th>
        <th>Lang:</th>
        <th>Id:</th>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <th>Rate:</th>
        <th>Date:</th>
        <th>Time:</th>
        <th>Ask:</th>
        <th>Bid:</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<sub>(I removed the `console.log` calls to make the answer a little shorter)</sub>

Comment: No mention of jQuery in the question. I would highlight this as a dependency of your answer. Perhaps offer an answer without dependencies too?

Comment: @naomik: `$('#count').text(count);` <-- from the question. OP is using jQuery. It appears he hasn't added it as a tag, so I fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla js way would be to write a loop that inserts values into your table

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see the results

```js
function createTd(text) {
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.textContent = text;
  return td;
}

var data = [
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6},
  {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}
];

var table = document.querySelector('table');

data.forEach(function(row) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.appendChild(createTd(row.a));
  tr.appendChild(createTd(row.b));
  tr.appendChild(createTd(row.c));
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  <tr>
<table>
```

---

All that DOM creation is a chore tho, right?

Here's a nice way to do it with React.

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see the results

```css
table td {
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx">
var data = JSON.parse('{"query":{"count":29,"created":"2015-07-07T07:36:44Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"rate":[{"id":"USDARS","Name":"USD/ARS","Rate":"9.1187","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"9.1228","Bid":"9.1187"},{"id":"USDAUD","Name":"USD/AUD","Rate":"1.3371","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"1.3374","Bid":"1.3371"},{"id":"USDBHD","Name":"USD/BHD","Rate":"0.3770","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"0.3790","Bid":"0.3770"},{"id":"USDBRL","Name":"USD/BRL","Rate":"3.1391","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"3.1392","Bid":"3.1391"},{"id":"USDGBP","Name":"USD/GBP","Rate":"0.6429","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"0.6429","Bid":"0.6429"},{"id":"USDCNY","Name":"USD/CNY","Rate":"6.2076","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"6.2088","Bid":"6.2076"},{"id":"USDHRK","Name":"USD/HRK","Rate":"6.8681","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"6.8982","Bid":"6.8681"},{"id":"USDDKK","Name":"USD/DKK","Rate":"6.7667","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"6.7671","Bid":"6.7667"},{"id":"USDEGP","Name":"USD/EGP","Rate":"7.8323","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"7.8550","Bid":"7.8323"},{"id":"USDSVC","Name":"USD/SVC","Rate":"8.7395","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"8.7445","Bid":"8.7395"},{"id":"USDEEK","Name":"N/A","Rate":"N/A","Date":"N/A","Time":"N/A","Ask":"N/A","Bid":"N/A"},{"id":"USDETB","Name":"USD/ETB","Rate":"20.6850","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"20.7880","Bid":"20.6850"},{"id":"USDEUR","Name":"USD/EUR","Rate":"0.9069","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"0.9070","Bid":"0.9069"},{"id":"USDHKD","Name":"USD/HKD","Rate":"7.7551","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"7.7558","Bid":"7.7551"},{"id":"USDHUF","Name":"USD/HUF","Rate":"286.5950","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"286.7000","Bid":"286.5950"},{"id":"USDINR","Name":"USD/INR","Rate":"63.3650","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"63.3700","Bid":"63.3650"},{"id":"USDIDR","Name":"USD/IDR","Rate":"13305.0000","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"13315.0000","Bid":"13305.0000"},{"id":"USDJPY","Name":"USD/JPY","Rate":"122.6800","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"122.7000","Bid":"122.6800"},{"id":"USDKWD","Name":"USD/KWD","Rate":"0.3027","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"0.3032","Bid":"0.3027"},{"id":"USDNZD","Name":"USD/NZD","Rate":"1.5029","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"1.5033","Bid":"1.5029"},{"id":"USDNOK","Name":"USD/NOK","Rate":"8.1454","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"8.1473","Bid":"8.1454"},{"id":"USDPKR","Name":"USD/PKR","Rate":"101.7300","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"101.7600","Bid":"101.7300"},{"id":"USDPHP","Name":"USD/PHP","Rate":"45.1385","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:35am","Ask":"45.1940","Bid":"45.1385"},{"id":"USDPLN","Name":"USD/PLN","Rate":"3.8152","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"3.8156","Bid":"3.8152"},{"id":"USDRUB","Name":"USD/RUB","Rate":"57.3075","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"57.3220","Bid":"57.3075"},{"id":"USDSGD","Name":"USD/SGD","Rate":"1.3536","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"1.3537","Bid":"1.3536"},{"id":"USDZAR","Name":"USD/ZAR","Rate":"12.4555","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"12.4569","Bid":"12.4555"},{"id":"USDSEK","Name":"USD/SEK","Rate":"8.4893","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"8.4906","Bid":"8.4893"},{"id":"USDCHF","Name":"USD/CHF","Rate":"0.9435","Date":"7/7/2015","Time":"8:36am","Ask":"0.9436","Bid":"0.9435"}]}}}');

var Table = React.createClass({
  renderRow: function(row) {
    return (
      <tr key={row.id}>
        <td>{this.props.data.query.count}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.query.created}</td>
        <td>{this.props.data.query.lang}</td>
        <td>{row.id}</td>
        <td>{row.Name}</td>
        <td>{row.Rate}</td>
        <td>{row.Date}</td>
        <td>{row.Time}</td>
        <td>{row.Ask}</td>
        <td>{row.Bid}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Count</td>
          <td>Created</td>
          <td>Lang</td>
          <td>Id</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Rate</td>
          <td>Date</td>
          <td>Time</td>
          <td>Ask</td>
          <td>Bid</td>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.data.query.results.rate.map(this.renderRow, this)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
});

React.render(<Table data={data} />, document.body);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it dynamically by formatting your html like this

```
 <table id='results'></table>   
 $.each(json.query.results.rate,function(i,item))
{
    var table=$('#results'),
     newRow = table.append($('<tr/>'));
    for(var p in item){
    newRow.append('<td>'+normalizeProperty(p)+'</td><td>'+item[p]+'</td>')
    }
}
```

the `normalizeProperty` function is a function that allows you to convert properties into  user-friendly names. Here is an example

```
  function normalizeProperty(p){
    p=p||"";
    return p.replace('_','').toUppercase();
  }
```

Comment: You're not appending any <td> dynamically as Itaws Wants.

Comment: `normalizeProperty`? All caps names are suddenly "user-friendly"?

Comment: as I said, it is only an example dude